# Redirect script making image referencing impossible

Tags: url-routing

I have a site that I run off the back of another site. In order to save on hosting etc. the domain points to a script and depending on the url that is in the address bar it redirects accordingly to a subfolder which holds the separate sites. I am happy with this and it works a treat. So when it hits url 1 it goes to "www.domain1.com/url1/Home/Index" and when number 2 is typed in it goes to "www.domain2.com/url2/Home/Index". url1 and url2 being the subfolders.

The problem comes when i am developing another site that is going off the back of the original. i have the site developed in vs and am about to release and obviously all of the image urls, script urls etc are completely wrong as they don't take into account the subfolder within the site. they all used /images/site/image1.jpg etc. this means that they are looking from the root and not from my subfolder url.

is there a simple way of implementing this so that i can develop it using vs and not have to change every image reference every time i release code?

i realise this probably has an incredibly easy answer to my problem - i just can't seem to find anything that fits.

Any suggestions?

slight addition to this - when my site loads it loads to the default page - and therefore when i use ../images/site etc this works when the url contains Home/Index, but not when it hits it on the default url which doesn't include the folder and page qualification.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this was left unanswered. When referencing in MVC you need to use the tilde (~) to reference the route of the application. So in my instance i have two sites and using the tilde notation if referenced the route of the application, of which each were specified as different routes.